# Is there a way to open the PerfMon with specified counters?

Tags: windows, perfmon

I am trying to write a program in which when you can open up the PerfMon and it will already have a certain set of counters displaying. This set of counters can be specified by the user. I really thought this would not be an uncommon thing but I have not found anybody talking about this online.

My question is how can I tell the PerfMon which counters to show when it starts up? I considered creating my own .PerfmonCfg file but it is a binary file and I could not find any documentation on the layout of the file (didn't really expect to, either.)

*Alternatively, is there a way to add in the PerfMon into my program (.NET framework program)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's an ActiveX control available for this.  Right-click the Winforms toolbar, Choose Items, COM tab, tick the "System Monitor Control" item.  Drag it onto your form and set its properties.  The normal context menu is available as well.

The programming guide [is here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd408124%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: Awesome! Never knew that "Choose Items" existed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this by opening an MMC (start-->mmc.exe) and then adding a Perfmon instance to the MMC. Add whatever perfmon counters you want.  You can then save the entire mmc to the desktop with a name based on your counters, like "processor utilization." Close the mmc, reboot the computer, etc. The next time you open the mmc, it will display the counters you originally added to the console.